# How to hand calculate classification in neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, math, neural-network, classification

I have a homework question that tells me to do this:

For the run with 20000 iterations, use the weights (of the four middle neurons, and the single output neuron), to hand-calculate the classification. In other words, when 0,0,1 is the input, use the weights to process this input, and show that the output would be 0.00765428, to use my output above as an example. Remember to pass the summed weights through the sigmoid (non-linear) function [look at the code, for the sigmoid formula that involves exponentiation]! Do this for all the four input triples. The point of this is to make you see this: once the weights have been learned, it's a straightforward process to handle incoming data to generate outputs [it is not complex/mysterious!]. In this exercise, we're simply using the training data and the learned weights, to hand calculate the outputs; in much more complex situations, the network will be fed new (so far unseen) data, which it will process using learned weights.

I have no idea where to even start processing by hand
I know I have to go through the functions and do the math myself, but I'm not sure what to input for self.weight or how far back in the process I'm supposed to go to start calculating the output. I'm just generally confused

**I'm supposed to do calculations for each of the four input triples ([0,0,1], [0,1,1], etc), but I don't know how to make each calculation specific to each input since all the triples are in the same array which is inputed for x in the nn class.**

This is the code:

````
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+ np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1.0 - x)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.input      = x
        self.weights1   = np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1],4) 
        self.weights2   = np.random.rand(4,1)                 
        self.y          = y
        self.output     = np.zeros(self.y.shape)

    def feedforward(self):
        self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
        self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))

    def backprop(self):
        # application of the chain rule to find derivative of the loss function with respect to weights2 and weights1
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)))
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T,  (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) * 
                                            sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))

        # update the weights with the derivative (slope) of the loss function
        self.weights1 += d_weights1
        self.weights2 += d_weights2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.array([[0,0,1],
                  [0,1,1],
                  [1,0,1],
                  [1,1,1]])
    y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
    nn = NeuralNetwork(X,y)

    for i in range(10000):
        nn.feedforward()
        nn.backprop()


    print(nn.weights1)
    print(nn.weights2)
    print(nn.output)```
````

Comment: Do exactly as the feedforward function defines. Where the np.dot function is matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Fish11 do you have any idea how i can make separate calculations for each of the input triples from the X array?

Comment: You can do them separately, it might make it easier.  Start with one input triple, calculate the output and so on.  You can also just do them all at once and the math works out.  The activation function should be done element-wise.